# Pass Windows credentials to remote WCF service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, azure, azure-active-directory

I have a remote WCF service, hosted on IIS. Then I have a ASP.NET MVC website hosted on Azure Websites.

The website uses Azure Active Directory to authenticate the user and it works fine. However, the WCF service requires correct Windows (domain-based) credentials in order to return results.

When I instantiate the service within my ASP.NET MVC app, I am using:

```
SomeService.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient ("SOAP");
client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel = System.Security.Principal.TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation;
```

This is backed by the `Web.config` file:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
  <binding name="SOAP" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
           maxBufferSize="20000000"
           maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="200000000"
           maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>

    <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
      <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

When I run this ***locally***, it works fine - I am picking up the credentials from the local AppPool and those are valid to access the WCF service. However, once I deploy the website to Azure, the above breaks because obviously the service is not aware of the credentials that I have locally.

**Question:**

Is there a way for me to pass Windows credentials to the WCF service through the browser without breaking the AAD auth stack, since I only need those for the WCF connection and nothing else? I am perfectly fine with showing a system prompt for credentials.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing but I want to call said web service from javascript not from C# using a .NET Service Client like you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the windows credential like so...

```
 SomeService.ServiceClient client = new ServiceClient ("SOAP");
 client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That would imply either hard-coding the credentials or me building a custom prompt to pass these in. Before I do that, I wonder if there is a built-in way to do so without the overhead. Thanks!

Comment: No worries - Have you tried passing over System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials

Comment: DefaultCredentials represents the system credentials for the current security context in which the application is running, so it will pick up the AppPool context on the server and not my local machine.